# C# .Net SQL Server 2012 - insert file - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows-server-2012-r2, sqlexception

I am attempting to insert a file into a sql file stream. The file I have been using in my tests is only 87 KB.

I have a SQL Server 2012 Enteprise instance running on a Windows 2012 R2 Server and a web server (2012 R2). The app running on the web serve hundreds of transactions / minute with the SQL Server with no issues.

Every time I attempt to execute a stored procedure that accepts a `varbinary(max)` parameter I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I was able to avoid the error when I removed to `varbinary(max)` from the stored procedure.

This is why I can come to the conclusion that this is were my issue is.

I get the same issue attempting to convert the `varbinary` to a base64 `varchar(max)`

Code samples - this is an attempt to call the stored procedure synchronously.

```
//
//This is an attempt to call the stored procedure synchronously.
public static void InsertFile1(string ProjectKey, string FileName, string ClientID, string FileType, Byte[] File, int FileCategoryId)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPROC", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectKey", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = ProjectKey;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = FileName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = ClientID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = FileType;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = File;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileCategoryId", SqlDbType.Int, 5).Value = FileCategoryId;

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("InsertClientFileVoid3", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("InsertClientFile", ex);
    }
}
```

This is an attempt to call the stored procedure asynchronously.

```
//
//This is an attempt to call the stored procedure asynchronously.
public static void InsertFile2(string ProjectKey, string FileName, string ClientID, string FileType, Byte[] File, int FileCategoryId)
{
    try
    {
        E2EStream(CancellationToken.None,  ProjectKey,  FileName,  ClientID,  FileType, File, FileCategoryId).Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("InsertFile", ex);
    }
}

//
//Function that does the async call to SQL Server
private static async Task E2EStream(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string ProjectKey, string FileName, string ClientID, string FileType, Byte[] File, int FileCategoryId)
{
    using (SqlConnection writeConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ETLWarehouseSalesforce"].ToString()))
    {
        Task openWriteConn = writeConn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        await Task.WhenAll(openWriteConn);

        using (SqlCommand writeCmd = new SqlCommand("[Publishing].[Insert_File]", writeConn))
        {
            writeCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            writeCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectKey", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = ProjectKey;
            writeCmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = FileName;
            writeCmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = ClientID;
            writeCmd.Parameters.Add("@FileType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = FileType;
            writeCmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = File;
            writeCmd.Parameters.Add("@FileCategoryId", SqlDbType.Int, 5).Value = FileCategoryId; 

            await writeCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the stored procedure that is called from C#

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertFile]
    @ProjectKey varchar(30) = ''
    ,@FileName varchar(300) = ''
    ,@ClientID varchar(300) = ''
    ,@FileType varchar(300) = ''
    ,@File varbinary(MAX) = null
    ,@FileCategoryId int = 1
AS
BEGIN

    print 'Stuff will happen here';

END
```

Calling this version of the procedure works.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertFile]
    @ProjectKey varchar(30) = ''
    ,@FileName varchar(300) = ''
    ,@ClientID varchar(300) = ''
    ,@FileType varchar(300) = ''
    --,@File varbinary(MAX) = null
    ,@FileCategoryId int = 1
AS
BEGIN
    print 'Stuff will happen here';
END
```

Work around stored procedure on DB-A

```
USE [DB-A]

ALTER PROCEDURE [Publishing].[Insert_File]
    @ProjectKey varchar(30) = ''
    ,@FileName varchar(300) = ''
    ,@ClientID varchar(300) = ''
    ,@FileType varchar(300) = ''
    ,@File varbinary(MAX) = null
    ,@FileCategoryId int = 1
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC [DB-B].[Publishing].[Insert_File] @ProjectKey, @FileName, @ClientID, @FileType, @File, @FileCategoryId;
END
```

Error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. 
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Did you forget to set the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` in the async case, or did I simply miss it?

Comment: Dirk - Thank you for the catch there.  I simply missed that in the example.  I have updated the async snippit.  Still receiving the error.

Comment: Added information...  When I debug from my local machine it throws the same error so that tells me not specific to to something on the web server.  Also if I pass null into the varbinary param it works.  Could this have something to do with SQL terminating the connection for things it considers to be large amounts of data?

Comment: @dirk - Thank you for the catch there. I simply missed that in the example. I have updated the async snippit. Still receiving the error.

Comment: Additional Information... I have a working work around but this does not fix the core issue.  Before the failing sproc on DB-B is called several other connections are made to another database (DB-A) of the same server.  I created a procedure DB-A the will call the procedure from DB-B and this is working.  If I try calling the original procedure in a test with no other db connections it works(connect DB-B only).  Thoughts?

Comment: Added workaround code. "Work around stored procedure on DB-A"